# What is a function that has O(n^2) and Ω(n), but does not have a complexity of (n) or (n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

It can be any made up function but I don't know how to build a function that has these constraints. There is meant to be a well-known algorithm that I'm not sure of that satisfies these conditions as well for best, worst and average cases.

Comment: Based on the definition of function orderings: https://cathyatseneca.gitbooks.io/data-structures-and-algorithms/content/analysis/notations.html, if you pick an algorithm that has a time complexity of n < Theta(n) < n^2 then you have for free the required upper and lower bounds. Figuring out algorithms for what lies in between is left up to the reader.

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong, but Insertion Sort satisfies these constraints.

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of them.

For example:

1. All ϴ(n log n) algorithms. E.g. MergeSort's time complexity is ϴ(n log n) which means it's O(n log n) and Ω(n log n). Then MergeSort's time complexity is O(n^2) and Ω(n) but isn't ϴ(n) nor ϴ(n^2).
2. Insertion Sort's time complexity is O(n^2) in the worst case scenario and it's Ω(n) in the best case scenario. But isn't ϴ(n) nor ϴ(n^2).
3. Brute force check of an string S in the string T when |S| = n and |T| = 2n. The time complexity is O(n^2) in the worst case scenario and it's Ω(n) in the best case scenario. But isn't ϴ(n) nor ϴ(n^2).

Comment: You seem to be confusing Ω and O with best and worst case respectively; for example, insertion sort *is* ϴ(n^2) in the worst case, not just O(n^2).

Comment: Thank you! How do I create my own function that has these constraints or what is an example of one?

Comment: @kaya3 It's true that insertion sort is ϴ(n^2) in the worst case, not just O(n^2). But the op asked about a looser condition. That's why I chose that word selection. It's not that i confuse anything. Check that all above is true and specifically chosen to answer the question.

Comment: The part where you said *"But isn't ϴ(n) nor ϴ(n^2)."* is not true - insertion sort is ϴ(n^2) in the worst case, and also in the average case, but you wrote that it isn't ϴ(n^2). That's why I commented. The same applies for substring testing.

Comment: @kaya3 Consider algorithm's time complexity over all possible inputs (do not restrict the input to match best, worst or average case).

Comment: If you're considering all possible inputs then you're measuring the average case.

Comment: @kaya3 A paragraph of the book Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, page 44: "Even when we use asymptotic notation to apply to the running time of an algorithm, we need to understand which running time we mean. Sometimes we are interested in the worst-case running time. Often, however, we wish to characterize the running time no matter what the input.  In other words, we often wish to make a blanket statement  that covers all inputs, not just the worst case. We shall see asymptotic notations that are well suited to characterizing running times no matter what the input." Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't know why you think this quote supports your claim that insertion sort isn't ϴ(n^2). It doesn't, and your claim is false.

Comment: @kaya3 Insertion Sort's running time is not ϴ(n^2) if you consider all possible inputs because of input: [1, 2, ...., n].

Comment: "Often, however, we wish to characterize the running time no matter what the input." That means: consider all possible inputs and apply the definitions.

Comment: You are confused about some fundamental definitions. Try this as an exercise: which mathematical function from the integers to the reals describes insertion sort's time complexity "for all possible inputs"? And which complexity class does that mathematical function belong to?

Comment: @kaya3 If you claim that if an algorithm's running time in the worst case scenario is ϴ(n^2) then the algorithm's running time over all possible inputs is ϴ(n^2) there is nothing i can do by now to change your mind.

Comment: I have obviously not said any such thing, and I don't think anyone other than you will read what I wrote and think that I have said that.

Comment: The example I gave cover such case to show that it not right to talk about time complexity of an algorithm without specifying if you are taking into consideration worst, best, average or a personalized scenario.